# reactjs and firebase: not redirecting to admin-dashboard and need to click twice before login

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

My admin has a custom claim property:

```
admin: true
```

I'm checking when logging in:

```
  async function handleLogin(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    try{
      await login(email, password);
      currentUser.getIdTokenResult().then(idTokenResult =>{
        if(idTokenResult.claims.admin){
          console.log("is admin: "+idTokenResult.claims.admin);
          setIsAdmin(true);
        }
      })
      
      if(isAdmin){
        history.push("/admin/dashboard");
      }else{
        if(currentUser.emailVerified == false){
          emailNotVerified();
        }
        else{
          history.push("/user/dashboard");
        }
      }
    } catch{
      wrongEmailOrPass();
    }
  }
```

But I'm having 2 issues:

1. every type of user is getting redirected to /user/dashboard
2. I need to click twice before logging in. The first time I click it'll give me incorrect email/password and the next time it'll redirect me to the dashboard page

Although I'm not sure is this some kind of state issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One think I can notice in your code is that you don't handle this async call properly and it wont behave as you expect it to. Try to change this:

```
currentUser.getIdTokenResult().then(idTokenResult =>{
        if(idTokenResult.claims.admin){
          console.log("is admin: "+idTokenResult.claims.admin);
          setIsAdmin(true);
        }
      })
```

to this:

```
const idTokenResult = await currentUser.getIdTokenResult();

if (idTokenResult.claims.admin) {
  console.log("is admin: " + idTokenResult.claims.admin);
  setIsAdmin(true);
}
```

And the second part is as you asumed the `state`. You set the state `isAdmin` and continue on with your synchonous code. You can set that satate but store it also in a variable for your code that comes after it.

I would also recommend to use the `onAuthStateChanged` listener to detect auth state changes:

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    var uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

Comment: Where would the onAuthStateChanged go? Cloud functions or my AuthContext?

Comment: AuthContext. It's a client side call.